# I am looking for a new update functions or suggestions to fix my existing one

Tags: php, mysql, database

In the code I gather data from my database then depending on the values of the data I will update it. I can retrieve the values but I can't update them I need help with the syntax of my update function or a different type of function.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","timeclock");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}else{
    echo "connected";
}
$x=2;
timein($x);
function timein($x){
    $con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","timeclock");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }else{
        echo "connected";
    }

    $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM emplo`enter code here`yeedatabase WHERE employeeID=$x ORDER BY employeeID" );
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $inout = $row['inOut'];
    }

    echo $inout;

    if($inout == 1){
        echo "hello";
        $con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","timeclock");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }else{
            echo "connected";
        }
        $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM employeedatabase WHERE employeeID=$x ORDER BY employeeID" );
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $inout = $row['inOut'];
            $row['inOut']=2;
        }
        echo "</table>";

        echo $inout;
        $outa=2;
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE employeedatabase SET inOut='$outa' WHERE employeeID='$x'"); 
    }
}

?>-## Heading ##
```

the mysqli query function is not working I need either a new function or better syntax for my mysqli function.

Comment: Define 'not working'.

Answer (score 0):

"Not working" isn't very helpful, in future errors and what is put in and does/doesn't happen is helpful.

But it looks like this line needs changing from

```
SELECT * FROM emplo`enter code here`yeedatabase WHERE employeeID=$x ORDER BY employeeID" );
```

to

```
SELECT * FROM employeedatabase WHERE employeeID=$x ORDER BY employeeID" );
```